# Formalise the following statement in first-order logic (FOL)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

The following is the statement of the problem and my approach also. Can any one guide me on whether have I done it correctly. if something is wrong then please correct me. Thank you

Problem: Formalise the following statement in first-order logic (FOL), making clear what your atomic predicate symbols stand for and what domains of any variable are:

1. "Not all the students in the discrete mathematics class are smarter than everybody in the linear algebra class."
2. Is there an equivalent formula to represent the statement? If yes, then what is it?
3. What are free and bound variables in your formula for part(1)

My calculations have led to the following answers:

1. Let $S(x):$ The Students in the discrete mathematics class are smarter than those in linear algebra class then, the answer to first part is:
   $\neg\forall x\in S(x)$
2. $\neg\forall x\in S(x) \equiv \exists x\in \neg S(x) $
3. $\neg\forall x\in S(x)$  is the only variable and it is bounded.

Comment: IMO the symbolization needs more predicates: Student,  DM class, LA class and Smarter-than

Comment: Having said that, YES: "Not all" can be equivalently expressed with $\lnot \forall x$ and $\exists x \lnot$

Comment: Juts to add to the previous comment. $\lnot \forall x \in S(x)$ is not a formula. You should have something like $\lnot \forall x \in S(x): \varphi(x)$.

Comment: What about free and bounded variables? Are they OK, in part 3?

Comment: @Ameer it is OK and not OK at the same time. You are correct in identifying that $x$ is a variable, and that it is present in the quantifier, hence must be bound. The not OK part is that since $\lnot \forall x \in S(x)$ is not a formula, it does not make sense to talk about bound and free variables (these notions are applicable to formulas only). 

What you have, i.e. $\lnot \forall x \in S(x)$, is just a quantifier without an expression. It is a shorthand for $\lnot (\forall x: S(x) \rightarrow ...)$

Comment: Can you help me in the answer of part 1?

Comment: @Ameer I think a good start will be to figure out which predicates you need. There are, of course, several ways to rewrite 1 as a formula of first order logic. I would suggest analysing what kind of 'objects' you have in the sentence. For example, there are students, and classes. These two can be unary predicates. Then students may attend classes, this can be expressed by a binary predicate $x attends y$. And so on. After you have figured out all the predicates you may need, just add implications, quantifiers, etc.

Comment: See this is solution I have arrived at for part 1 & 2. Is it fine now? If not then further guidance will be appreciated.                                                       
1. Let $A(x): x$ is a student in DM Class,
$B(y): y$ is a student in LA Class, $C(x,y): x$ is smarter than $y$, then we have $\neg\forall x$ $\forall y$ ($A(x)$ $\land$ $B(y)$$\rightarrow$ $C(x,y))$

2. $\exists x$ $\forall y$ ($A(x)$ $\land$ $B(y)$$\rightarrow$ $\neg$$C(x,y))$

Comment: @Ameer Expression 1 looks alright, although whether it is fine depends on the domain. In your case, your domain is the set of all students, and your formula works in this case. If the domain is the set of all 'things', e.g. students, classes, marshmallows, etc., then your formula is problematic. So you need to check the problem statement to be absolutely sure. Regarding 2, there is a problem. Your expression says that there is a DM student that is not smarter (aka 'thicker') than everybody else in the LA class. This is rather strong, and what you really want to express is that for this ...

Comment: ... for this DM student there is (at least) one LA student that is smarter than they. This expression can be obtained from your 1 but carefully 'pushing' the negation all the way to $C(x,y)$.